# Setting a character limit on a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create conditions in my spreadsheet. One of them is to limit the number of characters in cells in column B to 20. If the data inputted exceeds then I want to flag it by creating a message in column A.

I have tried to adapt code but cannot figure it out. I currently have a message box coded, but I want to change that to concatenate to already flagged errors in column A.

```
Sub character_length()
For Each cell In Columns("B:B")
        If Len(cell.Value) > 20 Then
            MsgBox " Can't enter more than 15 characters"
            cell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If the data inputted exceeds then I want to flag it by creating a message in column A.

Comment: Why not use Data Validation to not let the user put in more than a certain number of characters?

Comment: `cell.Offset(,-1).Value = .cell.Offset(,-1).Value & " Can't enter more than 15 characters"` instead of `MsgBox`. But yeah this is exactly the job of *Data Validation*.

Comment: Also `cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 15)` would probably be less frustrating than `cell.Value = ""`, but that's your call ;-)

Comment: ...wait is it 15 or 20? Declare some `Const maxLength = 20` (or `= 15`), and use that instead of hard-coding `15` and `20`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub character_length()

Dim cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("B1:" & "B" & LastRow)
If Len(cell.Value) > 20 Then cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & " Can't enter more than 20* characters"
Next
End Sub
```

The following code loops through each cell in Column B up until the last row in Column B with a value. This limits the number of rows to just those in your data set. You don't want excel checking all 1 million+ rows probably. Then it uses an IF statement to loop through the length of each cell, similar to your original code. It then concatenates what is already in the left cell (Column A) with the new warning.